# Using jQuery Zoom on Lazy Loaded Image

Tags: javascript, jquery, zooming, lazy-loading

I almost have this working.

I am able to get part of the image to zoom, but not the whole thing. It seems as though the wrapper is being created and `.zoom()` being run on both the image and the image placeholder `transparent.gif`

**Here is the HTML before the JS function:**

```
<img alt="Transparent" class="lazy zoomer" data-original="assets/find_pro.png" src="/assets/transparent.gif">
```

**Here it is after:**

```
<span style="display: inline-block; position: relative; overflow: hidden;">
  <span style="display: inline-block; position: relative; overflow: hidden;">
    <img alt="Transparent" class="lazy zoomer" data-original="assets/find_pro.png" id="tester" src="assets/find_pro.png" width="800" style="display: block;">
    <img src="assets/find_pro.png" class="zoomImg" style="position: absolute; top: -120.24242424242425px; left: -58.392144638404px; opacity: 0; width: 1211px; height: 539px; border: none; max-width: none;">
  </span>
  <img src="/assets/transparent.gif" class="zoomImg" style="position: absolute; top: 234.17100371747213px; left: 108.07543640897755px; opacity: 0; width: 45px; height: 45px; border: none; max-width: none;">
</span>
```

When I delete the extra image node and extra `span`, everything works fine:

```
<span style="display: inline-block; position: relative; overflow: hidden;">
  <img alt="Transparent" class="lazy zoomer" data-original="assets/find_pro.png" id="tester" src="assets/find_pro.png" width="800" style="display: block;">
  <img src="assets/find_pro.png" class="zoomImg" style="position: absolute; top: -100.84848484848484px; left: -402.1153366583541px; opacity: 0; width: 1211px; height: 539px; border: none; max-width: none;">
</span>
```

**Here is the JS I'm using:**

```
  $('img.lazy').load(function() {
    if ( $( this ).hasClass( "zoomer" ) ) {
      $(this)
        .wrap('<span style="display:inline-block"></span>')
        .css('display', 'block')
        .parent()
        .zoom();
    }
  });

  $("img.lazy").lazyload({ 
    threshold : 200,
    effect : "fadeIn"
  });
```

[**Link to plugin**](http://www.jacklmoore.com/zoom/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I *tracked* down your problem.  The problem is $('img.lazy').load();.  It's being called twice.  The first time is when the page loads (transparent image).  The second time is when lazyload does its thing and makes the non-transparent image appear in its place.

Your second problem was that zoom() was acting upon your transparent image (the src of your img.zoomer).

The third problem was that this change negated lazyload's utility. I have finally devised a solution that works!

To solve your problem, do:

```
$('img.lazy').load(function() {
  $(this).lazyload({ 
    threshold : 200,
    effect : "fadeIn"
  });
  if ($(this).attr('src') === $(this).attr('data-original') && $(this).hasClass('zoomer')) {
    $(this)
      .wrap('<span style="display:inline-block"></span>')
      .css('display', 'block')
      .parent()
      .zoom();
  }
  console.log($(this).attr('src') + ' loaded');
});
```

Comment: I'm not sure why but this still isn't working for me!

Comment: Maybe a callback to apply the wrapper in .lazyload would work better?

Comment: I don't see the changes reflected on your 'test doc.'

Comment: Ohh I see that there is another problem!  Your zoom is acting upon the 'src' attribute of your image you want zoomed (in this case it's transparent) - not the data-original.  Let me edit my solution.

Comment: Jared, I'm sorry I had to unaccept your answer because .attr('src', function(){return $(this).attr('data-original')}) was being called on page load ... this meant that all of my full size images were being downloaded at page load.. I thought I had figured out a better way, but nope, still struggling!!!

Comment: Good point - I'll devise a solution next morning/afternoon if you haven't figured it out yet.

Comment: Morning has arrived and I solved the problem.  Please revisit my answer.

Comment: You seriously deserve a medal for effort.